# Папка Resources. Обращение к частям спрайта в Multiple режиме? Unity

Tags: unity3d

Есть Спрайт `Sprite1` в папке `Asset`, в папке `Resources`. Я его нахожу с помощью данного кода, всё работает:

```
    public SpriteRenderer rend;
    void Start()
    {
        rend.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprite1");
    }
```

Потом получается я данный спрайт разрезаю на 4 части, то есть перевожу из `Single` в `Multiple`. Получается 4 подспрайта `Sprite1_0`, `Sprite1_1`, `Sprite1_2`, `Sprite1_3`. Немного не понимаю тогда в данном случае, как обратиться, например, к спрайту `Sprite1_2`.

Ни так не выходит:

```
rend.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprite1_2");
```

Ни так:

```
rend.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprite1/Sprite1_2");
```

Если кто знает в чём проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Никак. `Resources.Load` вообще не стоит пользоваться, превращает проект в помойку. Просто объявите поле `[SerializeField] private Sprite[] _sprites;` и укажите ссылки на спрайты в инспекторе.

Comment: @Yaroslav, а вот допустим, что у героя есть для примера 100 скинов. Всё равно лучше через Sprite[] работать, а не через Resources.Load? А вообще Resources.Load сильно тормозит игру?

Answer (score 0):

Это, нажаль, невозможно. Лучше создайте публичное поле и в инспекторе перетяните нужный спрайт.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/626303)

Comment: @Spatz В это ответе есть решение проблемы. Создать поле и дать ему значение в инспекторе.